# Libcurl how to not show all this information

Tags: c, curl, block, codeblocks, libcurl

How to not show all this info?
All I do is using little edited FTP example and i dont want that info to be shown.

edit: added full code from main.c

image in link: http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/71e9/oyhctzcdjxakzxzfg.jpg

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

struct FtpFile {
 const char *filename;
 FILE *stream;
};
static size_t my_fwrite(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
  struct FtpFile *out=(struct FtpFile *)stream;
  if(out && !out->stream) {
  /* open file for writing */
  out->stream=fopen(out->filename, "wb");
  if(!out->stream)
  return -1; /* failure, can't open file to write */
}
return fwrite(buffer, size, nmemb, out->stream);
}

int main()
{
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
struct FtpFile version={"version.txt", /* name to store the file as if succesful */NULL};

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
curl = curl_easy_init();

FILE *file_verzija;
int trenutna_verzija;
int nova_verzija;
char pitanje_za_update;

file_verzija=fopen("version.txt","r");

fscanf(file_verzija,"%i",&trenutna_verzija);

fclose(file_verzija);


printf("Current version %i",trenutna_verzija);

printf("\nChecking for updates...\n");


if(curl)
{
    /*You better replace the URL with one that works!*/curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,"http://elektro-srb.com/site/muffin_finder_files/version.txt");
    /* Define our callback to get called when there's data to be written */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, my_fwrite);
    /* Set a pointer to our struct to pass to the callback */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &version);
    /* Switch on full protocol/debug output */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    if(CURLE_OK != res)
    {
        /* we failed */
        printf("\nerror");
    }
}

if(version.stream)
    fclose(version.stream); /* close the local file */

file_verzija=fopen("version.txt","r");

fscanf(file_verzija,"%i",&nova_verzija);

fclose(file_verzija);

if(trenutna_verzija != nova_verzija)
{
    printf("\nUpdate found! New version is %i",nova_verzija);
}
else
{
    printf("You are running latest version of Muffin Finder!");
}

if(trenutna_verzija != nova_verzija)
{
    printf("\nUpdate? y/n");
    scanf("\n%c",&pitanje_za_update);
    if((pitanje_za_update == 'y') || (pitanje_za_update == 'Y'))
    {
        //UPDATE
    }
    else if((pitanje_za_update == 'n') || (pitanje_za_update == 'N'))
    {
        //pokretanje stare
    }
}


curl_global_cleanup();



return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comment following line:

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

Answer (score 1):

You should construct a `WRITEFUNCTION` option, to prevent it from using `stdout` for printing.

See here: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html.

Search for "WRITEFUNCTION". You should implement the function (and I assume you would like to leave it empty).

**EDIT:** As the manual states, you should do the following:

Implement a function to replace the default **stdout**:

`size_t outputFunction(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata) {}`

When you initialize the CURL structure, use this option:

`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, outputFunction);`

Comment: Actually I am not really god with programming so i need more help :) Can You tell me what exactly to do ?
I added code

Comment: What you mean by copied one? I used ftpget.c example from http://curl.haxx.se/ and added some text file reading? I just didnt understand what you said me to do so I ask for more detailed help.

Comment: I just cant get it to work :/ Thanks for help but I will try alternative way like hiding program window and writing everything needed in allegro window. Thanks again :)

Comment: What is not working? It is pretty simple. Add the function definition at the start of your code. You should call `curl_easy_setopt` inside the `if (curl)` code block. If you may, please mark this question as answered.

Comment: I tried everything what you said and it still prints all that stuff on screen. So no question is not answered.